# APScheduler does not run scheduled tasks: Flask + uWSGI

Tags: python, flask, uwsgi, apscheduler

I have an application on a Flask and uWSGI with a jobstore in a SQLite. I start the scheduler along with the application, and add new tasks through `add_task` when some url is visited.
I see that the tasks are saved correctly in the jobstore, I can view them through the API, but it does not execute at the appointed time.
A few important data:

`uwsgi.ini`

```
processes = 1
enable-threads = true
```

`__init__.py`

```
scheduler = APScheduler()
scheduler.init_app(app)
with app.app_context():
    scheduler.start()
```

`main.py`

```
            scheduler.add_job(
                id='{}{}'.format(test.id, g.user.id),
                func = pay_day,
                args = [test.id, g.user.id],
                trigger ='interval',
                minutes=test.timer
            )
```

in `service.py`

```
def pay_day(tid, uid):
    with scheduler.app.app_context():
     *some code here*
```

Interesting behavior: if you create a task by going to the URL and restart the application after that, the task will be executed. But if the application is running and one of the users creates a task by going to the URL, then this task will not be completed until the application is restarted.
I don't get any errors or exceptions, even in the scheduler logs.
I already have no idea how to make it work and what I did wrong. I need a hint.

Answer (score 0):

[From the APScheduler FAQ:](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/3.x/faq.html?highlight=Flask#how-can-i-use-apscheduler-with-uwsgi)

> uWSGI employs some tricks which disable the Global Interpreter Lock
> and with it, the use of threads which are vital to the operation of
> APScheduler. To fix this, you need to re-enable the GIL using the
> --enable-threads switch. See the uWSGI documentation for more details.

I know that you had enable-threads = true in uwsgi.ini, but try the to enable it using the command line.

Comment: Right now I'm calling `scheduler.start()` in the `@app.before_request` function and so far it's working correctly. This is a possible solution, but I'm currently observing the behavior.